# pexpect.EOF: End Of File (EOF). Exception style platform

Tags: python-2.7, pexpect

With pexpect I am spawning child process and doing 'ssh' remote box. It was working fine from last many days, suddenly now i whenever i am trying to spawn child process it's throwing below Error. not sure what is going on.

Till now i was using pexpect 3.1, i encounter this problem. so I  upgrade it to 3.2, but still facing same issue.

```
>>> child = pexpect.spawn('ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no centos@192.168.2.23')
>>> child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT,'[P|p]assword: '])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1418, in expect
    timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1433, in expect_list
    timeout, searchwindowsize)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 1521, in expect_loop
    raise EOF(str(err) + '\n' + str(self))
pexpect.EOF: End Of File (EOF). Exception style platform.
<pexpect.spawn object at 0x7fe923a8b710>
version: 3.2
command: /usr/bin/ssh
args: ['/usr/bin/ssh', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', 'centos@192.168.2.23']
searcher: <pexpect.searcher_re object at 0x7fe923a8b750>
buffer (last 100 chars): ''
before (last 100 chars): 'AL PROSECUTION.\r\nPermission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive).\r\r\n'
after: <class 'pexpect.EOF'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: 255
flag_eof: True
pid: 2202
child_fd: 3
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
```

Answer (score 6):

```
child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, 'pattern', pexpect.EOF])
```

> Some UNIX platforms will throw an exception when you try to read from a file descriptor in the EOF state. Other UNIX platforms instead quietly return an empty string to indicate that the EOF state has been reached.
>   If you wish to read up to the end of the child’s output without generating an EOF exception then use the `expect(pexpect.EOF)` method.

For the details, you can follow [this](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#exceptions).

Hope it will helpful to you.

Answer (score 4):

The error is actually inside your `ssh` command execution. Seems like you need an ssh key to connect:

```
before (last 100 chars): 'AL PROSECUTION.\r\nPermission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive).\r\r\n'
```

The easiest way to solve this problem is running `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no centos@192.168.2.23` manually and fixing the ssh key problem.

Comment: Expect [pexpect.TIMEOUT,'[P|p]assword: '], but got pexpect.EOF.